# Characters being substituted in <code> tags across all browsers, all research dead ends or highlights regex tutorials

Tags: html, configuration, substitution

[x replaced with " in all '<'code> text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc5l5.png)

As the image shows, every instance of the x character in '<'code> tags is replaced with a double quote. Similar substitutions happen with the y character, and most infuriatingly of all, the { open bracket, which is replaced with an empty space.

This ONLY happens in text wrapped in '<'code> tags. Any other text on this machine displays just fine.

I'm at my wits end. No matter what I google, all I find are regex tutorials or CSS & JS tricks for switching out characters on the page. I'll reiterate, this is a display issue on my end. It affects every browser on my machine, and every input setting I've fiddled with has been ineffectual. Yes, I've removed all input shortcuts. I'm on an iMac macOS High Sierra. Any nudge in the right direction would be so helpful, this has been driving me crazy for so long.

Few more notes, I'm the 3rd or 4th developer to use this workstation. I wasn't super familiar with macs before starting this job, but so far haven't run into any other weird config issues that have been left for me (other than this one possibly).

Also, I can confirm for sure that this problem is contained to this work station-- the same text on the same page renders just fine on my tablet and phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the 'courier' font on my browsers was just bad. Switched it to 'courier new,' and it's all displaying just fine now. So I guess if your type is consistently displaying wrong in the same spots and circumstances, check your fonts.